# Using ctrl as modifier to produce swedish letters å, ä & ö on us keyboard while typing

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, input-language

Pretty new to Linux (currently running Xubuntu). I want to be able to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and the button where å, ä & ö would be on a Swedish keyboard. I have tried using both `xbindkeys` together with `xte` and using `xdotool`.

I have also tried creating keyboard shortcuts using the built in keyboard utility in Xubuntu, with both the aforementioned methods as well as trying to write my own .sh files to do the job. I have not had any success for hours now.

tl;dr:

I want to produce å using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, ä using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> & ö using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> whilst typing regularly into anywhere that takes text.

Answer (score 8):

I'd choose another approach and create a custom keyboard layout instead.

Add this to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "swedish" {

    include "us(basic)"
    name[Group1]= "English (US, with åäö)";

    key <AD11> { [ bracketleft,  braceleft,  aring,       Aring      ] };
    key <AC10> { [ semicolon,    colon,      odiaeresis,  Odiaeresis ] };
    key <AC11> { [ apostrophe,   quotedbl,   adiaeresis,  Adiaeresis ] };

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

and this to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`:

```
<variant>
  <configItem>
    <name>swedish</name>
    <description>English (US, with åäö)</description>
  </configItem>
</variant>
```

That will let you access å, ä and ö via <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (<kbd>RightAlt</kbd>), which is the conventional way to access third and fourth level symbols.

Comment: You might add what ( non basic? ) US keyboard layout enables this.

Comment: @psusi: What enables it is the `include "level3(ralt_switch)"` statement, so if you follow the suggestions in the above answer it will be enabled. (That's also the case for several of the standard English layout variants.)

Comment: I've tried to add the above fragment to  /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml on my 17.10 install, putting it in <xkbConfigRegistry><layoutlList><layout><variantList> after the <configItem><name>us</name> but AltGr+those keys didn't do anything. Did I put it in the wrong place? Do I need to tell something to refresh from the file?

Comment: @mabraham: You should run `systemctl restart keyboard-setup` (or reboot).

Comment: Is there any way we could use Ctrl key instead of Alt? This combination breaks my thumb :-)

Comment: @mikabytes: RightCtrl can be used. To do that, replace the suggested `include` statement above with: `include "level3(switch)"`