# How to use Mode_switch and xmodmap in current Ubuntu versions?

Tags: 17.10, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell, xmodmap, xkb

For years I used the following `~/.Xmodmap` file to get german umlauts quickly, e.g. when I press the `ALT_R + a` I get `ä`. A nice shortcut compared to using the compose key:

```
keycode 108 = Mode_switch
keycode  38 = a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keycode  30 = u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keycode  32 = o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keycode  39 = s S ssharp ssharp ssharp ssharp
keycode  20 = minus underscore endash endash endash endash
keycode  60 = period greater ellipsis ellipsis ellipsis ellipsis
keycode  61 = slash question emdash emdash emdash emdash
```

Note: I'm using the *Happy Hacker Keyboard*, which has no `ALT_GR` key. The `keycode 108` is sent by the right ALT key and `Mode_switch` generally  corresponds to the 2nd and 3rd values above.

Since 17.10 all combinations only result in a warning sound, nothing else happens. I noticed the same on Fedora 27, so maybe it's related to new *xkb* settings and / or Gnome Shell?

Any ideas how I can archiev this under current **Gnome Shell** setups?

Comment: Assuming you use the English (US) layout, you can create a keyboard layout variant by editing the us symbols file. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/873950), which was written in response to a similar question, may provide the guidance you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Gunnar Hjalmarsson](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson), I found enough information in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873933/using-ctrl-as-modifier-to-produce-swedish-letters-%c3%a5-%c3%a4-%c3%b6-on-us-keyboard-while/873950#873950). Here's what I did:

To include some new key settings, I added this to the end of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "us-de" {

    // include all the definitions from us(basic), I just want to add to it

    include "us(basic)"
    name[Group1]= "English (US, with german umlauts)";

    // add german umlauts

    key <AC01> {    [     a,    A,  adiaeresis, Adiaeresis      ]   };
    key <AD07> {    [     u,    U,  udiaeresis, Udiaeresis      ]   };
    key <AD09> {    [     o,    O,  odiaeresis, Odiaeresis      ]   };
    key <AC02> {    [     s,    S,  ssharp,     ssharp          ]   };

    // and some other keys

    key <AE11> {    [     minus,    underscore, endash, endash  ]   };
    key <AB09> {    [    period,    greater,    ellipsis,   ellipsis    ]   };
    key <AB10> {    [     slash,    question,   emdash, emdash  ]   };

    // have ALT_R as level 3 switch

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

And to have a variant I can select from *Settings > Region & Language*, I added
the following to the end of the *variantList* for `English (US)` in this XML
file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`:

```
<variant>
<configItem>
    <name>us-de</name>
    <description>English (US, with german umlauts)</description>
</configItem>
</variant>
```

After a `sudo systemctl restart keyboard-setup.service` I could select the new
layout variant from *Settings > Region & Language*.