# setxkbmap us command messed with language settings: can't use second language

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, language-support

I have two languages installed: English and Russian. I have a keybind that allows me to switch between the two using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> combination. When I run

```
setxkbmap -query
```

it used to output something like

```
layout: us, ru, us
```

I've been following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084836/german-umlaut-with-windows-key-a-o-u-s) question's answer and I used this command:

```
setxkbmap us
```

and now the

```
setxkbmap -query
```

outputs

```
layout: us
```

and although I can switch between ru and en (in the top language panel in DE), I only type in english.

I can also do

```
setxkbmap ru
```

and then I'll only be able to type in russian.

I'm not sure how to go back to my previous set up - I used the GUI to set it up (Settings and Gnome Tweaks) and from what I can tell the GUI settings stayed the same - I still have the two languages.

Comment: This is expected and normal. Reboot your system and it will go back to normal as before and you can select and type in different layouts.

Comment: @Raffa How does it work internally? Is there a `.xkb` file that got updated after my command?

Comment: Yo gave it only one layout option. Give it two and it will give you two like this `setxkbmap us,ru` : )

Comment: @Raffa Thank you! That seems to have worked. I probably put a space between which gave me error. But my previous layout somewhy had three groups: us,ru,us. Why? Should I do `setxkbmap us,ru,us`?

Comment: one `us` is enough. It will work the same way as `us,ru,us` both will work the same as far as I know and you can even do `us,ru,us,ru,us,ru,us` no difference. And it is temporary until reboot and will go back to before.

Answer (score 1):

```
setxkbmap -layout ru,us
```

Then check if the input language matches the one displayed in the gui. If not:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,ru
```