# Danish key mappings on english keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Most nice keyboards don't include æ, ø and å keys, so I was wondering if it would be possible to bind something like caps lock to some of the keys `{capsl + ' = æ}`, `{capsl + " = 'ø'}` and, `{capsl + " = å}` or something similar?

Comment: This may help: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.en

Comment: This is one idea: https://askubuntu.com/questions/873933/using-ctrl-as-modifier-to-produce-swedish-letters-%c3%a5-%c3%a4-%c3%b6-on-us-keyboard-while

Comment: use Ubuntu settings keyboard shortcuts custom to send keys with xdotool?

you might have to send it to clipboard and paste from there. you need to know the code for the character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you map <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to the [Compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) (you can do it through `Settings` → `Keyboard` → `Layouts` → `Options`, look for "Position of Compose key"), they will be accessible through <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (å), <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> (æ), and <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> (ø). Note those are three keypresses in a sequence, not a combination to press at once. Use uppercase letters to get the uppercase variant.

This is the method I personally use to type Danish, since I grew up with the Polish layout, which is based on standard US QWERTY with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, and hate the Danish layout (as well as any other "national" layout not based on standard QWERTY) with a passion, for the simple reason that it makes it impossible to switch between languages easily because they all move things around in incompatible ways.

Answer (score 4):

See 'update', below.

Thanks for asking this question! You may have seen the `altgr-intl` layout, which enables you to access accented characters on a US qwerty keyboard. This was based on the Microsoft International Keyboard and that wasn't my smartest choice (as Microsoft included some exotic letters like ð (eth) that nobody uses).

So, we tried to make a (new) US layout, that supports all Western European languages (in the sense that all accented characters in those languages are available through **one** AltGr keystroke). We called it `altgr-weur`.

Right now, the project is ready but before I offer this to be included in the already numerous layouts, I'd like people to test it. A few are working on it, but no Danes yet.

So, please install the [layout](https://altgr-weur.eu/) and let me know if it suits your needs. <del>I'm pretty confident, after all the letter frequency analysis we went through.</del>

The special characters in Danish are Å (a-overring) on AltGr-<del>z</del> q, Ø (o-slash) on AltGr-t and Æ (...) on AltGr-<del>x</del> w.

Update: after some discussion, we decided to re-think our layout and changed quite a bit (early 2021). The link to the (updated) website still works.

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Wow that is very cool! However I really want to be able to do some mappings where the characters originally is on the danish keyboard. I haven't really used other european languages characters a whole lot. However, I would love to test it out when I get my keyboard. It is a really cool project, and I could definitely see it taking off!

Comment: In that case, follow the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873933/using-ctrl-as-modifier-to-produce-swedish-letters-%c3%a5-%c3%a4-%c3%b6-on-us-keyboard-while) that @GunnarHjalmarsson suggested and modify just the three keys you want. Use the guide mentioned in the answer to integrate your very personal layout. Good luck!