# danish characters custom key combinations

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

So the problem is I have a standard QWERTY keyboard, but I want to be able to type specific danish characters. I have tried to follow the example of this post [Using ctrl as modifier to produce swedish letters å, ä & ö on us keyboard while typing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873933/using-ctrl-as-modifier-to-produce-swedish-letters-%c3%a5-%c3%a4-%c3%b6-on-us-keyboard-while). Which I cannot make workfor some reason.

My current active keyboard layout is English US.

I have insterted the following below.

`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "danish" {

    include "us(basic)"
    name[Group1]= "English (US, with åæø)";

    key <AD11> { [ bracketleft,  braceleft,  aring,       Aring      ] };
    key <AC10> { [ semicolon,    colon,      odiaeresis,  Odiaeresis ] };
    key <AC11> { [ apostrophe,   quotedbl,   adiaeresis,  Adiaeresis ] };

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

`/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`
I have added the variant as the first in the list under English (US) like below

```xml
  <layoutList>
    <layout>
      <configItem>
        <name>us</name>
        <!-- Keyboard indicator for English layouts -->
        <shortDescription>en</shortDescription>
        <description>English (US)</description>
        <languageList>
          <iso639Id>eng</iso639Id>
        </languageList>
      </configItem>
      <variantList>
        <!-- Added danish mappings -->
        <variant>
                <configItem>
                        <name>danish</name>
                        <description>English (US, with åæø)</description>
                </configItem>
        </variant>
```

and restarting the keyboard service with `systemctl restart keyboard-setup`.

I do not have any combinations the expected mappings does not work, I have tested that the Meta R/Alt R and the key presses is detected as expected.

My current selected language is displayed as `English (United Sates)` (not `English (US)` as the mapping might suggest it should?)

I cannot find the other `variants` listed below under input sources like

````xml
          <configItem>
            <name>colemak</name>
            <description>English (Colemak)</description>
          </configItem>
        </variant>
        <variant>
          <configItem>
            <name>dvorak</name>
            <description>English (Dvorak)</description>
          </configItem>
        </variant>
``` etc.
````

Comment: Did you add _English (US, with åæø)_ to your list of input sources and switched to it?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I most likely have not! How would you do that? I don't seem to be able to find it under Region & Language input sources

Comment: Well, there is where it should be selectable for adding if your modifications are correct. Can you please clarify a few things (by editing your question): 1. In which file did you put the first block of code? 2. Please describe where exactly in `evdev.xml` you put the section for the danish variant.

Comment: Btw, you need to reboot or at least relogin for the changes to be visible in _Region & Language -> Input sources_.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I have edited the question, and rebooted. And (US, with åæø) does not appear in the list of possible input sources

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I found it, I was not pressing English (United States) for the input sources. I expected it to be a individual input source

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson turns out, it prints swedish characters. But otherwise works as expected!

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. :) You may want to check out in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/dk` which names represent æ and ø. Anyway, great that you figured it out at last!