# Bind key shortcut to letter å

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I would like to have `Super+[` to bind to the character å,
and `Super+Shift+[` to bind to Å,
and a few other shortcuts to type Swedish characters on the American layout.

I have tried to use the Custom shortcuts menu, where I can bind `xdotool key --clearmodifiers aring` to `Super+i`, but for some reason, I cannot bind it to  `Super+[`.
Also, binding to Super+O is also not possible.
This is very strange.

How can I bind shortcuts to type one (or several characters)?

EDIT: The answer in [Using ctrl as modifier to produce swedish letters å, ä & ö on us keyboard while typing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873933/using-ctrl-as-modifier-to-produce-swedish-letters-%c3%a5-%c3%a4-%c3%b6-on-us-keyboard-while/873950#873950) solved my issue!

Comment: For me, the Super+[ combinations can be set and work. However, it does also not work for me with Super+o, even tough I also can set the key. (tested with "gnome-calculator" as command). Also, instead of `--clearmodifiers`, try with `keyup` where you first have xdotool release the assigned hotkey and eventually introduce a short delay (0.2 s or more).

Comment: @vanadium right, so the issue is not with running a command, but to make the specific shortcut work - why cant Super+[ be used? and Super+O, which is even stranger...

Comment: To type the å character, I use the "English (intl. with AltGr dead keys). This lets me type things like äåéëþ or even ©®æ°. It uses the right alt (and shift) as the modifier keys. If you don't find a suitable answer, then this may be the direction you'd like to go.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/873950/159370). It can probably be modified to use <Super> instead of <AltGr> to access 3:rd and 4:th level symbols.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: Nice to see that the answer to that other question fixed it for you. Voting for making this question a duplicate then.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson yes, it does, I managed to make it work!